# TeamCity re run tests until find last working revision / revision which broke it

Tags: unit-testing, teamcity

As we only run our unit tests once a day it can happen that multiple changes led to a failing test. We then go into the changes list and trigger the tests for each change until we find the one responsible for breaking the test.

How can we automate this? We want TeamCity to run the unit tests again for the different changes (some binary search logic would be a bonus) until it finds the culprit.

How would you call this feature? I'm looking at the options to enable this but haven't had any luck so far.

Thanks for input and pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've developed a TC plugin to deal with this. See https://github.com/sferencik/SinCity. Read the docs and see if it suits you. I'm happy to help you further if you need.

The docs also mention the only other alternative I'm aware of: https://github.com/tkirill/tc-bisect. That has the bisect functionality ("binary search logic") but I'm not sure what state it's in.

Comment: I installed your plugin and will test it, thanks for the great work!

Comment: I'll appreciate any feedback, or contributions!